# Set per_process_gpu_memory_fraction in tensorflow.js tfjs-node-gpu

Tags: tensorflow.js

is it possible to set the max allocate GPU memory for tfjs-node-gpu ? By default it take 100%, and I haven't view any information on the API doc.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For now it is not possible to set a memory limit on the GPU; node does not yet offer a control over the gpu used and neither `tfjs-node-gpu` in itself.

However, you can use the memory footprint to check manually the size allocated with `tf.memory`